# Installing cushion vinyl over carpet

Tags: carpet, vinyl-flooring

[image]

I plan to put some cushion vinyl over my corridor carpet. I will be using proper cut sheets and not just off cuts as shown in the picture.  Later on I will pull the carpet out from underneath the vinyl and glue it down.

I know this is not the most professional way but I need to do it now as the carpet is making me sick and I don’t have time to place boards then glue vinyl on right now.  I know there will be bubbling in the meantime.

My questions are:

1. if I cut the vinyl to shape while it is on the carpet, when I remove the carpet can I expect the vinyl to fit nicely or might a gap develop in which case how much extra sheet should I keep on the edges?
2. In order to cut the vinyl to shape, if I place the carpet on top of the vinyl as a template then draw the shape and cut it out, can I get a good fit or will this not work, if so why?

Thanks

Comment: just remove the carpet and be rid of it. It Has to come up anyway,  covering The carpet temporarily may not remove the potential for you to get sick. Walking on the vinyl  on top of carpet will possibly stretch it and cause divets.

Comment: I kinda agree with Alaska man but the vinyl may be cracked and damaged by walking on it cracked vinyl is trash in my opinion so you would be better off to gut the carpet now it will only take a few minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, not the best way to do this. The vinyl will shrink a bit when cut if not glued down so don't try to cut it to fit. I'd keep at least an inch so you can trim to fit as you already know how hard it is to trim it accurately.

Using the carpet as a template won't work either because carpet edges are never cut to fit exactly. Their edges are stuffed down between the walls and tack strips. I'd wait until you're ready for the final installation and then get some construction paper and make an exact template by laying out the paper in the hallway and taping it all together. then lay the template over your sheet vinyl and cut with a straight edge and utility knife.

Comment: Paper templates will help but the trim should hide a little deviation in the cut so I usually undersize slightly and I never have bubbles or buckling because it is tight.

Comment: jack are you saying regardless of whether you put the vinyl over the carpet or after removing the carpet, if you use no glue then as you cut it the vinyl will shrink?  therefore you need to cut all edges and repeatedly until it falls into place rather then cut into place?

Comment: @EdBeal you are saying to under size over a template.  Is that because the reasons Jack has given e.g. the carpet has extended deepening edges, or is it even without a carpet, how can this be if the vinyl shrinks as you cut it(as Jack said)?

Comment: @JamesWilson Whether on top or not, over time vinyl will shrink a bit if just laid on a surface.  Ed was referring to undercutting an exact paper template just a bit because the molding would hide a small gap and you do need to roll the vinyl which will stretch it when using the adhesive.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to put something over the carpet put a plastic hall runner, vinyl flooring is not suitable for placement over carpet.